# Representing a graph in XML

Tags: xml, graph

Hi what will the best possible way to represent a graph in XML, where a node can be the child of a parent node and may be the parent of another child node. It can refer to itself, and multiple nodes can have same parent. And a node can have multiple parents. 
All nodes are from same class. I want to build it efficiently, so that if I can learn about a child node from a parent node I can go to the specific child tag without having to iterate all the nodes. Is it possible?
for example here is an overview,

```
A->B,C,D

B->C,D
```

it may look like

```
<Node name=A>
 <childNode name=B>
 <childNode name=C>
 <childNode name=D>
</Node>

<Node name=B>
 <childNode name=C>
 <childNode name=D>
</Node>
```

So are there any better approaches than this? Whenever I get a child from A i.e. B, than I will have to basically iterate through all Nodes and match there name attribute with B to find the Node that represents B. Can I somehow do it faster?

Comment: "*a tree ... where a node can ... refer to itself ... and can have multiple parents*" I don't think [that word means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Definition) what you think that word means.

Comment: @Rob yeah, sounds like a Graph to me...

Comment: The best way to represent a tree in XML is... well, in XML. "XML is a syntax for trees."

Comment: oh yeah it is actually a graph, not a tree, i overlooked the multiple parent thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have a graph, and not a tree as you first thought, why not use [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/)?

> GraphML is a comprehensive and easy-to-use file format for graphs. It
>   consists of a language core to describe the structural properties of a
>   graph and a flexible extension mechanism to add application-specific
>   data.
>
> Unlike many other file formats for graphs, GraphML does not use a
>   custom syntax. Instead, it is based on XML and hence ideally suited as
>   a common denominator for all kinds of services generating, archiving,
>   or processing graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't say I fully understand your problem, but I think you're trying to rebuild a (directed) graph in a high level language from an XML file, right? It'd help to know what kind of representation you have in the high level language. Or the language, actually. Assuming C++, and an adjacency list:

I'd first create a `map<string, Node*>`, mapping the names to the nodes. My XML would look like this:

```
<edge from='A' to='B' />
<edge from='A' to='C' />
<edge from='A' to='D' />
<edge from='B' to='C' />
<edge from='B' to='D' />
```

This is rather compact, and I can parse it with a SAX parser, which is always nice. As I read the edges sequentially, I check to see if I have the nodes in my map already: if not, I store them:

```
if(mapping.find(from) == map.end()) map.insert(make_pair(from, new Node()));
if(mapping.find(to) == map.end()) map.insert(make_pair(to, new Node()));
```

Once both end nodes are in the map, we can add the edge by:

```
mapping[from]->add_egde_to(mapping[to]);
```

Once the parsing is complete, you have the nodes in the map, nicely ordered by name.

Anyhow, you may want to look at Wikipedia's summary about [graph representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29#Representations), that may give you ideas.

Comment: Hi, will it be efficient if say I search for the number of child nodes from A? Will not it take more time (As it will need to go through the whole file) than the way I presented my XML? The file in this case will be a large file of more than 100K entries.

Comment: Ah, so you'd like to fetch data from the XML without reading the graph into memory? Yeah, that's a different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RDF/XML.

RDF is a simple data model for the semantic web (linked-data) consisting of triples (Subject, Predicate, Object). It can represent graphs and is serializable in a number of formats including xml, json (json-ld) and turtle.